# Ajax: Check if item already exist in HTML before Append new item

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with `Student` which list new students where you can accept or not. There are two ways to update the list, you can either manually reload the page, or/and the Ajax method (via service bus) will automatically update the list when a new student register.

However there's a problem in this way, If a student register, and I start/reload the page(reading all newly registered students), then Ajax will also "update" the list by adding additional div, which cause two of same student in my list.

So I need to set a duplicate-check inside Ajax before it post - Does this current student already exist in html content?

```
var url = "/Home/GetNewStudentFromQueue";

function getData() {
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        var id = data;
       $.post("/Home/Test", { "id": id },function (data) {
         if (data) {    

    //HERE: If statement, if div with @item.Id and class studentInfo doesn't already exist in html content

             $("#newStudent").append($('<div id=\"'+ id +'\" class=\"studentInfo\"> ' +
             '<br/> ' +
             <b>Student Name: </b>' + data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName +
             .....
           +'</div>'));

           }
         });

        getData();           
    });
} getData();
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="newStudent">
        @foreach (var item in Model) {

                <div id="@item.Id" class="studentInfo">                           
                    <br />
                    <b>Student name: </b> @item.FirstName @item.LastName
                    .......
                    <hr />
                </div>                
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: Unclear what your trying to achieve here. If you ajax call is returning all `Student`, then just emtpy the contents of `<div id="newStudent">` in the ajax call before adding them

Comment: @StephenMuecke My Ajax call is only returning one `Student`, not all.  It simply add new `Student` to the list, so my page wont require the page to be reloaded to show the new data.

Comment: You can always return the ID of the student and then check if a element with that `id` already exists - `if ($('#' + data.Id)) { // it exists } else { // add it }` but what your doing does not really make sense

Comment: @StephenMuecke `if ($('#' + id))` is this how you check if a specific div already exist in html content? It was true even if there wasn't any.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Bad scenario: Page is closed, (the queue from service bus is getting filled with new `Student`). Then when the page is turned on, it reads all `Student` from database in controller and pass to view -> Now Ajax also kicks in and read from queue and fill the list as well. So there's now some duplicated `Student`. That's why I have to check if there's already `Student` in HTML list.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `.length` - `if ($('#' + data.Id).length == 0) {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130826/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-fagol).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something might help..

```
if(data)
{
  var existing =  $("#newStudent #"+id).html();
  if(existing != undefined && existing.length > 0)
  {
      // without container i.e. div with id 
       var htmlWithoutContainer = '<br/> ' +
         <b>Student Name: </b>' + data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName.....'
       $("#newStudent #"+id).html(htmlWithoutContainer ) 
  }
  else
  {
      // with container i.e. div with id  
      var yourNewHTML = '<div id=\"'+ id +'\" class=\"studentInfo\"> .....'
      $("#newStudent").append(yourNewHTML);
  }
}
```

It just give you an idea, please take care of syntax error.